# Edit ribbon width in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, ribbon

By the default, ribbon in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 contains 5 items, "more" button and a bunch of free space.
Is it possible to increase the items count in the ribbon?
If so, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this setting is not editable and you would not be able to increase the number of visible items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your button by using customization of Application Ribbon or Entity Ribbon.
However number of buttons can been seen at a time not sure you can achieve this. 
However, those buttons you want to see in 5 items you can achieve this using customization. 
There is index field associate with each button in ribbon that decide the priority to display.
You can set this priority using [Ribbon workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)